# PHP and ZIP creation: Can standard zip "options" be applied

Tags: php, zip

Does anybod know how PHP ZIP functions can be used to apply standard **zip** "**options**" when creating zip files. So far all my searches have not turned up anything.

In particular I am interested in applying either the "**-ll**" and "**-l**" options so I can offer either WIN or NIX versions of zipped text based files (*cgi and php and text files etc*) from a nix web site. The contents will be zipped on the fly with some files edited as added for each specific customer.

I am aware of building and using command line 'back-ticked' (*Perl*) or "passthru(.)" (*php*) methods but am hopeful there is a trick to do this using pure php i.e. ZipArchive().

Regards.

Comment: Can't you just `str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $fileContents)` for `-l` and `str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $fileContents)` for `-ll`? That's basically what the options do. Obviously, *before* the zip operation.

Answer (score 0):

You may end up falling back to shell_exec and just doing the zip using the native system, then you can pass the -ll or -l as you wish. http://php.net/manual/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

I think str_replace() is pretty obvious. But, that's memory intensive on large files.

I won't show all the code, but php has a seldom used feature where you can apply "filters" to streams, and the filters can be specified as part of the file url. It makes for a nice way to hook into certain filesystem operations that otherwise don't let you tweak behavior easily.

Once you define a filter with [stream_filter_register](http://www.php.net/stream_filter_register)(), then you should be able to pass a file url like `php://filter/string.to_unix_line_endings/resource=/path/to/the/file.txt` to the `ZipArchive::addFile()` method.

ultimately though, you could also just create a temp file, and copy the file contents over to it in chunks, str_replacing as you go, and then pass the tempfile name to `ZipArchive::addFile()` method as well. And that would be much easier to code.